# Authentication via User Interaction (Game play, using ML)

Tags: authentication, terminology, biometrics

Something you know (password), something you are (biometrics), something you have (key card/security key) are the typical authentication factors.

Several years ago I've seen a paper in which the users authenticated via interaction. In that case it was something like a jump-and-run. The specific way how people played was apparently enough to identify them. It also had a demo.

I think they also mentioned playing the piano as an option that could work as well.

**How is this type of "authentication via interaction" called?**

I'd be super happy if somebody could point me to a paper / a demo. No matter what I search, I only find people complaining that they cannot login into their game.

Comment: Relevant: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25013/is-behavioural-analysis-e-g-keystroke-dynamics-a-reliable-security-mechanism and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121824/could-keystroke-timing-improve-security-on-a-password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is authentication based on the **behavior** of the user. Examples are the way the user types on the keyboard ([keystroke dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_dynamics)), how they move the mouse, how they interact with the smartphone ... .

A common term for this is [behavior-based authentication](https://www.google.com/search?q=behavior+based+authentication). Since it is a kind of biometric authentication (how you are determines how you behave) it is also called [behaviorial biometrics](https://www.google.com/search?q=behavioral+biometrics).

Behavioral biometrics  are usually a weak authentication. How the user behaves can depend on the mood, time of day, consumption of alcohol and other drugs ... It takes also significant to collect enough behavior data. It is therefore usually only used in addition to other authentication, like tracking user interaction in the background to make sure that a user logged in with password behaves sufficiently similar to the past to ensure that it is still the same user and not an attacker who compromised the credentials.